# how to use custom accuracy in tensorflow federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

```
def hinge_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
     y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true) > 0.0
     y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_pred) > 0.0
     result = tf.cast(y_true == y_pred, tf.float32)

     return tf.reduce_mean(result)

def model_fn():

     keras_model_clone = create_baseline_model()
     return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
          keras_model_clone,
          input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
          loss=tf.keras.losses.Hinge(),
           metrics=[hinge_accuracy])
```

It throws an AttributeError: in converted code: `/home/bhatia87/.conda/envs/cent7/5.1.0-py36/tff/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py:496 report_local_outputs  *outputs[metric.name] = [v.read_value() for v in metric.variables]`

AttributeError: `'function' object has no attribute 'variables'`

Answer (score 0):

Values passed to the [`metrics` parameter to `tff.learning.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model) must either implement the [`tf.keras.metrics.Metric` interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric?version=stable), or be a no-arg callable returning a value implementing `tf.keras.metrics.Metric`.

Keras documentation provides pointers on implementing [custom metrics via the `Metric` interface](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#as-subclasses-of-metric-stateful) which may be useful here.

Comment: Thank you @Keith Rush for your response.